# Searching for waterfalls / water drops within an area of interest, return location and height

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, topography, surface, service-recommendations

Is there a system/service for finding or searching waterfalls or "water drop" (say 1.5m drop)? Or is there another (simply) way to gain this data?

- finding := Input a location and drop height, the system returns coordinates of candidates (much like a google-maps search for *restaurant*.
- searching := The user can look on a map, that clearly indicates (like a heat map) where and to what extend drops happen.

Example of what I imagine: Here on the Niagra Falls: 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible option would be to use **OSM-Data** (Open Street Map Data) and to rout your user's search request trough e.g. the [**Overpass API**](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

It will return e.g. waterfalls for a given AOI, including names and height

How to access it:

- **QGIS**: `QuickOSM Plug-In`. This allows you to access and download the data on your local PC. Great if you want to do some pre-processing to put it in a Web-GIS later on.
- **Web**: `OverpassAPI`, or directly in the browser e.g. via [`OverpassTurbo`](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). Great if you want to access the data dynamically and from your Web-GIS etc.

**QuickOSM Plug-In**:
Your search would look like this:
[image]
Resulting in an output of points and polygones holding some additional information like height in their attribute table, which you can easily use via the labeling in the layer properties to display the height. Moreover, you could also filter them to meet your desired height-limits:
[image]

**OverpassAPI**: Perform your search directly via the API (see [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) how to do this), or via a Web-front-end. Your query can be very basic. Such as:

```
    [out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["waterway"="waterfall"]( {{bbox}});
    way["waterway"="waterfall"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["waterway"="waterfall"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

Again, the output will be the same:
[image]
By the way: under the hood, the QuickOSM Plug-In is performing the same search via the OverpassAPI.